# quasiperiodic tilings: inverse semigroup -- non-commutative geometry connect?

Tags: noncommutative-geometry, inverse-semigroups

A Connes' [Noncommutative Geometry](http://www.alainconnes.org/docs/book94bigpdf.pdf) (1994) and M Lawson's [Inverse Semigroups](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/9810233167) (1998) contain sections on quasiperiodic tilings, yet as far as I can tell neither seems to refer to the other field of study.

What's the connection?